# Get Product Options for each Product in the Catalog in Magento

Tags: php, magento

This is using Magento 1.9.

I am trying to build a script that outputs all the product options for each product in the catalog into a CSV file.

I have tried using the code on this page: http://www.atwix.com/magento/configurable-product-attributes/

For this code:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');  
foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true) as $option) {
    echo $option['value'] . ' ' . $option['label'] . "\n";
}
```

I get no output, what-so-ever.

For this code:

```
$productAttributeOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
$attributeOptions = array();
foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
    foreach ($productAttribute['values'] as $attribute) {
        $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label']][$attribute['value_index']] = $attribute['store_label'];
    }
}
```

I get this error:

`Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple::getConfigurableAttributesAsArray() in /home/tws2/public_html/getopts.php on line 71`

Ive been unable to find anything else on the internet for getting at the product options of a product with PHP code.

**Can someone please explain to me how to use PHP to get at all the product options data for each product in the catalog, so I can output all this data into a CSV file.**

The purpose of this is to transfer the product options data over to an identical Magento server that has the same catalog, just missing the product options data. Once I have all the CSV file of product options I was going to make another script to write them into the identical Magento server. This is how Ive been advised to do this task in-house, if you have a better suggestion please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the configurable options of whole catalog, try this

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

  foreach ($collection as $product) {
   foreach ($product->getProductOptionsCollection() as $o) {
    $values = $o->getValues();

    foreach ($values as $v) {
        $v['product_id'] = $product->getEntityId();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($v->getData());
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: I start with `if ($products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')){` then `foreach ($products as $product){` and then I add your code from the line `if ($product->getId()) {` and I have a problem, I never get past the line `if ($product->hasCustomOptions()) {` despite the fact that I have 1000s of products and most of them have custom options. Do you know what is going wrong?

Comment: please see the usage of the variables properly. inside foreach its `$_product` and i have used `$product`

Comment: can you adjust your code so it works for all products in the catalog, and not just one?